# Font sizes for bullet points

Tags: style, fonts

Is it necessary that in a bullet point list, the font size of the bullet points should be the same as the fonts in the introductory sentence of the bullet list?

For example, in the following bullet list should the font size of the sentence 'The following animals......around with:" be the same as the bullet list below or can it be bigger? If so, it is okay I keep the font size for this as 13 and the bullet list as 11?

> The following animals should not be messed around with:
>
> - Elephant
> - Hippo
> - Water Buffalo

Answer (score 1):

It is not strictly necessary as bulleted lists are often introduced with a heading or other larger text. I would say to make sure that the font size does not go too small for readability but that there is no problem with the 2 being different sizes (though outside of a heading-list instance it might look a bit odd but that would not matter as much)